# How to change column datatype when loading csv in postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, dataframe, csv, types

I have a big script, the result is that the data is stored in a dataframe and then in csv. Then csv is opened and written to PostgreSQL. But there is a problem that the data type of one column is int4, and after opening csv the column format is 'text'. I cannot change the data type in the database, they must be there exactly as int. Tell me pls how to do it.

```
total.to_csv("C:/Users/.../total_type19.csv", index = False, sep =';')

conn5 = psycopg2.connect(dbname='', user='',
                       password='', host='', port = '')
cursor5 = conn5.cursor()


with open("C:/Users/.../total_type19.csv", "r",encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ";")
    for row in reader:
        # print(row)
        cursor5.execute(
            'INSERT INTO interaction_fillword (test_id,data_size,data_matrix, data_words_selection, data_colors, data_answers) VALUES(%s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)',
            (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5]))

conn5.commit()
```

The test_id column must be in int4 format

```
['312229', "['[{from:[3,4],to:[7,4],color:2},{from:[3,6],to:[10,6],color:3},{from:[5,8],to:[9,8],color:5},{from:[5,11],to:[10,11],color:6},{from:[1,0],to:[1,11],color:0},{from:[10,1],to:[10,6],color:4},{from:[3,0],to:[8,0],color:1}],']", '[\'["v","b","c","c","a","h","i","e","r","s","f","j"],["d","i","w","s","s","r","i","f","y","y","f","c"],["j","b","m","w","d","q","s","q","t","w","e","m"],["x","l","m","m","l","s","o","x","d","q","u","t"],["l","i","f","p","l","a","c","e","t","u","t","o"],["m","o","s","b","r","t","c","y","z","v","r","r"],["j","t","x","c","a","r","t","a","b","l","e","o"],["b","h","k","m","d","b","r","y","q","u","i","y"],["y","è","s","r","h","g","o","m","m","e","w","h"],["u","q","p","c","s","c","x","b","k","e","d","o"],["u","u","o","l","q","v","y","y","b","y","e","h"],["r","e","o","u","j","b","u","r","e","a","u","k"]],\']', '[\'"#ff0000","#00fe00","#0000ff","#d2ea9a","#407f76","#211f95","#e1f233"\']', '[\'"place","cartable","gomme","bureau","bibliothèque","feutre","cahier"\']']
```

This is an example of one line from csv. Looks bad but that's the way it should be

Comment: The code you posted doesn't change the data type from a single column in the PostgreSQL table. Make sure all your columns use the correct data type and you will be fine. Off topic: Why don't you use copy_from() to load the csv into the table? Much faster

Comment: Do you mean that the csv data comes in as string or the data will not pass test_id = int(row[0]).  Post a sample data row.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm pretty sure the data type of the column is not int. Tell me, can I somehow prescribe that the data is loaded in the desired format? Copy_from () just never used, but this method is clear to me

Comment: When trying to do int(row[0]), I get the error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'test_id'. Now I will post an example from csv

Comment: A CSV file is a text format so that is the only type you will get from it. Having an integer value as text is not an issue as it will be automatically cast to integer on entry per; `select '312229'::integer; 312229`. The exceptions would be empty strings or strings with non-numeric characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change your data to int or is it something like "m22" non-integer?

```
# to remove non-numeric digits from string
with open("C:/Users/.../total_type19.csv", "r",encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ";")
    header = next(reader )
    print(f"HEADER {header}")
    counter = 1 #or whatever number you want to start with
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        test_id =row[0]
        test_id = ''.join([i for i in test_id if i.isdigit()])
        if test_id == '':
            counter +=1
            test_id = counter
        else:
            test_id = int(test_id)
        print(test_id)
        cursor5.execute(
            'INSERT INTO interaction_fillword (test_id,data_size,data_matrix, data_words_selection, data_colors, data_answers) VALUES(%s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)',
            (test_id, row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5]))
```

Comment: When I add your code, I get the error "invalid literal for int() with base 10:"

Comment: does it print your row?  Can you post what it prints?

Comment: You edited and the code works, thank you very much

Comment: feel free to vote my answer up and add as answer.

Comment: Now there is a problem that headers with csv are written to the database. Most likely because test_id=0. Is it possible to change it somehow

Comment: ok, a counter can be added.  your row[0] was 312229.  Did it make it past that line?

Comment: Yes, she passed the test, now she is the second in a row. The first line is the headers from csv.

Comment: ok we can skip the headers.  I'll post

Comment: The 'header = next(reader )' is a good trick to remember :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [copy_expert](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert) from `psycopg2.

```
import psycopg2

conn5 = psycopg2.connect(dbname='', user='',
                       password='', host='', port = '')
cursor5 = conn5.cursor()

with open("C:/Users/.../total_type19.csv", "r") as csv_file:
   cursor5.copy_expert("COPY interaction_fillword FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER", csv_file)
```

The `CSV HEADER` will do a  couple of things:

1. Skip the header line automatically.
2. Take empty non-quoted strings as NULL.

`copy_expert` uses the Postgres [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) to do bulk data import(or export) a lot quicker then inserting. The down side is that `COPY` is all or nothing, either the entire import/export succeeds or a single error will rollback the entire thing.